# error occur while deploying c# application system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception a network-related or instance-specific

Tags: c#

i have developed application in C# visual studio 2013 with sql server management studio 2017. Its not publishing in my laptop. Moreover, when i create setup file and deploy in client PC it shows me the following error:
**system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception a network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server.(provider: named pipes provider, error.40-could not open connection to SQL.

guide me
regards

Comment: What SQL Connectionstring are you having? Can you reach that SQL server instance from that machine you are trying to run the program?

Comment: Have you installed and configured a SQL Server (not Management Studio) to use named pipes on your laptop?